# Perturbation theory with non-symmetric matrices

Tags: perturbation-theory

I have read about perturbation theory for symmetric matrices. Now suppose that $A$ is a symmetric real matrix, and $B$ is a real matrix (not necessarily symmetric). Suppose we know the eigenvalues of $A$, and are interested in the eigenvalues of $A + \epsilon B$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is a small quantity.

I want to apply the classical perturbation theory formulae to this problem. Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of, due to the fact that $B$ is non-symmetric?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are pitfalls, i.e., you cannot just use the results for symmetric matrices. See [Theorem 4.4 in these notes](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/498_13/eigenvalues.pdf) for the first-order correction to the eigenvalues in the general nonsymmetric case.

Comment: Thank you @James for this!